# JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, oop, object

## Why the output is

**[object Object]**:
can some one help me?
when i call the function search with name parameter I 
need him to give me all details

```js
<script>
    var friends = {};
    friends.bill = {
      firstName: "Bill",
      lastName: "Gates",
      number: "(206) 555-5555",
      address: ['Microsoft Way']
      };
    friends.steve = {
      firstName: "Steve",
      lastName: "Jobes",
      number: "(444) 111 000",
      address: ["Apple way"]
    };
    var list = function(obj) {
      for( var key in obj){
        console.log(obj);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += key + "<br>";
      }
    }

    var search = function(name) {
      for(var key in friends){
        if(name === friends[key].firstName){
          console.log(friends[key]);
          document.getElementById('search').innerHTML += friends[key] + "<br>";
        }
      }
    }
    // list(friends);
    search("Steve");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use :

```
console.log(friends[key].firstName + ',' + friends[key].lastName);
```

Or :

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(friends[key]));
```

When you log console.log(friends[key]) it will show type of object not object details

Answer (score 0):

Because `friends[key]` is an object, so when your try to use It as string you get `[Object object]`.

```
friends[key]; //{"firstName":"Steve","lastName":"Jobes","number":"(444) 111 000","address":["Apple way"]}
```

You have to use one of the object's properties:

`document.getElementById('search').innerHTML += friends[key].firstName + "<br>";`

```js
 var friends = {};
    friends.bill = {
      firstName: "Bill",
      lastName: "Gates",
      number: "(206) 555-5555",
      address: ['Microsoft Way']
      };
    friends.steve = {
      firstName: "Steve",
      lastName: "Jobes",
      number: "(444) 111 000",
      address: ["Apple way"]
    };
    var list = function(obj) {
      for( var key in obj){
        console.log(obj);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += key + "<br>";
      }
    }

    var search = function(name) {
      for(var key in friends){
        if(name === friends[key].firstName){
         alert(JSON.stringify(friends[key]));
          document.getElementById('search').innerHTML += friends[key].firstName + "<br>";
        }
      }
    }
    // list(friends);
    search("Steve");
```

```html
<p>
  <span id="demo"></span>
</p>
<p>
  <span id="search"></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `friends` is an object, try this

```js
    var friends = {};
    friends.bill = {
      firstName: "Bill",
      lastName: "Gates",
      number: "(206) 555-5555",
      address: ['Microsoft Way']
    };
    friends.steve = {
      firstName: "Steve",
      lastName: "Jobes",
      number: "(444) 111 000",
      address: ["Apple way"]
    };
    var list = function(obj) {
      for (var key in obj) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += key + "<br>";
      }
    }

    var search = function(name) {
        for (var key in friends) {
          if (name === friends[key].firstName) {
            console.log(friends[key]);
            document.getElementById('search').innerHTML += friends[key].address + "<br>";
             document.getElementById('search').innerHTML += friends[key].firstName + "<br>";
             document.getElementById('search').innerHTML += friends[key].lastName + "<br>";
  document.getElementById('search').innerHTML += friends[key].number + "<br>";
          }
        }
      }
      // list(friends);
    search("Steve");
```

```html
<div id="search"></div>
```

Comment: Wow John 
you are pro 
Thanks :)